# Determine hashing algorithm

Tags: hash, password-hashing

I have a plaintext and a hash output, two hash outputs to be precise.
One is HEX encoded, and I have no idea on the other one.

plaintext=halflife

hash=1e4dfacf77efceb3076bb551932e6e40

hash2=PN[6O265X^W6YEIK`/YJNVX54N\HY

I can't be actually sure which hash is output derived from my plaintext, and which isn't.
Is there a tool I could use to figure out how was my plaintext hashed, so it would come out like this?
If not, what procedures would you recommend?

UPDATE:
I now know that the hash2 is actually not the hash of the plaintext, but something else. I also know that if I change the plaintext > hash gets updated, and if I change hash back to it's original state > original plaintext is considered correct.

Comment: You are right in saying that you cannot determine which one is derived from your plain text this is a feature of hashing algorithms called preimage resistance where given the hash it is hard to determine the original text.

Comment: @Nat That's not what preimage resistance means.

Comment: @fkraiem        For a given h in the output space of the hash function, it is hard to find any message x with H(x)=h.

Comment: ... when given only h and nothing else.

Comment: Besides, preimage resistance also assumes the algorithm is known.

Comment: @Nat I know x and h but not H, and that's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @JanNovak       Yes but you also say that you do not know which one is acctually the plain text "halflife" therefor my point was due to preimage resistance it will be hard to determine which one is your plain text

Comment: @Nat my original thoughts were that both hashes were made from plain text "halflife". I did realise that these thoughts may be invalid and I made sure to point that out. Anyways, turns out it really isn't the case, and that only the hash is actually hashed plaintext "halflife"

Comment: @JanNovak      Thanks for making this clear to me i think your wording of your question confused me abit :)

Comment: You aren't going to go far with only one output and two potential outputs, unless you're very lucky. But you aren't lucky: neither hash1 nor hash2 are in a common hash format (hash1 could be an MD5 checksum, which is a bad but common way to hash passwords, but it isn't MD5("halflife")). You should dig deeper into the process that creates those values. [reverseengineering.se] might be a good place to ask questions if you get stuck while digging deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this tool to no avail

https://www.onlinehashcrack.com/hash-generator.php#res

My best guess is that the program is actually doing more than a simple hash, it may be a number of hash rounds or some other manipulations

You said that changing the plaintext makes the hash change. So you have a program which performs such unknown hash. Decompile it and work out the process behind. The algorithm is not "secret", it's stored in the executable

Comment: The thought had crossed my mind. Any ideas, based on the hash length, etc?

Comment: the hash is 16 bytes long (128 bits) so it may be a final stage of MD5, MD2 or RIPEMD-128. Hash length doesn't give you any hints on the actual algorithm behind. As I said, decompile the program and have a look, that's the best you can do